# Proving that $\mathbb{K}[[x_1,...,x_n]]$ is a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-writing

I'm following Mumford's proof in "The Red Book" for proving that a regular local ring is a UFD. He assumes that any $\mathbb{K}[[x_1,...,x_n]]$ is a UFD. I'm trying to find an intuitive, low tech proof for that. My best guess is an induction on $n$, $\mathbb{K}[[x_1,...,x_n]]=\mathbb{K}[[x_1,...,x_{n-1}]][[x_n]]$ (it's just a matter of reorganizing terms in the sum) and then proving the inductive step i.e.: any regular local ring that is a UFD, say $R$, implies that $R[[x]]$ is a regular local ring and a UFD. Proving the inductive step seems to me quite general and may involve deeper mathematics that I'd expect. So: is there a easy way for the inductive step? Is there a less general inductive proof?

Comment: One quick question: your post title indicates you're interested in the polynomial ring, but your post body is all about power series rings. Could you clarify a little bit?

Comment: Sorry, meant power series always

Comment: See the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952156/kx-1-ldots-x-n-is-ufd-for-k-field?rq=1), and a reference with proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477819/is-the-ring-of-formal-power-series-in-infinitely-many-variables-a-unique-factori).

Comment: The standard proof of this is by using Weirstrass preparation/division theorem. I would not consider it low tech, but I do not know your concept of low tech.

Comment: Not low tech, I will have to study that. Thank you all for your help